# How to play mp3 files on computer thru Android (just like what Gmote 2.0 does) of the same network?

Tags: java, android, port

I've seen how the GMOTE 2.0 runs on Android. The accessing of media files on computer is really cool and making them play makes it much cooler and the other features of it.

Now, I would like to make a program for android and for PC. What I want to make is like the GMOTE 2.0 but i only want the way it plays mp3 files over the PC. And my PC and Android is on the same newtork (same router).

Can someone give me advice on how this will be started and what would I be needing? 
Please help me I don't know how will this be started. Is it possible communicating thru ports? (Like TCP?)

Comment: That sounds like a huge project for someone who asks that kind of questions :| Did I get it right: You want to "remote control" what audio is played on your PC using an App on your Android phone. If so, you should start by deciding if you write your own player on the pc or use some existing software and use its API to control it remotely ...

Comment: Yes you are getting what I want. Can you cite some example of those existing software so i can check it? And also what will i be needing if i decide to write my own player on PC? Thanks in advance! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be difficult. Basically, you need to create two components:

1. **Remote control driver**: This application will be running on the computer. It should be able to do at least these things:

   - Export list of all songs. It depends on you, how sophisticated it should be. I would
     suggest to export all songs from the computer in a XML. It may look like this:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <list>
         <artist name="Fear Factory">
             <album name="Demanufacture" year="1995">
                 <song name="Demanufacture" track="01" filename="C:\MyMusic\FearFactory\01. Demanufacture.mp3" />
                 <song name="Self-bias resistor" track="02" filename="C:\MyMusic\FearFactory\01. Self-bias resistor.mp3" />
             </album>
         </artist>
         <artist name="Sybreed">
             <album name="Slave design">
                 <song name="Bioactive" track="01" filename="C:\MyMusic\Sybreed\bioactive.mp3" />
             </album>
         </artist>
     </list>
     ```

     To generate such a list, you'll need to define path to some local folder(s). Now you
     can go through the whole folder and read name of each file. Then you can use some
     library and read ID3 tags (which contains name of the artist etc) from these files.

     It should be very easy to generate this list.
   - Create an network interface, which will be listening on some TCP port and waiting for
     commands. If it receive some command, it'll just proceed some action or send response.
     You'll probably need these types of commands:

     - UPDATE_DATABASE: It will create XML as shown above and send it to your mobile
       mobile phone.
     - PLAY_SONG: Receive full filename (as shown in the XML) and start playing of that
       song in the background. There exists some libraries which can do this for you.
       Example with Slick2D:

       ```
       new Sound("some_music.wav").play();
       ```

       It's automatically started in another thread, so you don't have to worry about
       that. However, Slick2D is primary for game development, so it would be better to
       look for something else.

       Another possibility is to just start some media player (or console media player).
       But I wouldn't recommend that as it will be much more difficult to control
       whether the song is playing or not, or to pause it.
     - PAUSE_SONG
     - GET_CURRENT_SONG: It'll just look for the name of currently playing song and send
       it back.

   This application doesn't have to be graphical (but it'd be nice). The simplest and ugliest
   version might be something like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       TCPServer server = new TCPServer(999);
       Sound     sound  = null;

       for (;;) {
           String command = server.accept();

           if (command.equals("UPDATE_DATABASE)) {
               // generate xml
               server.sendData(xml.getRawContent());
           } else if (command.equals("PLAY_SONG")) {
               String filename = server.accept();

               sound = new Sound(filename);
               sound.play();
           } else if (command.equals("PAUSE_SONG")) {
               if (sound.playing()) {
                   sound.pause();
               } else {
                   sound.play();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Most of classes I've used probably doesn't exist. Remember, that this is just a very
   simplified example.
2. **Application for mobile phone**. And that's up to you. You'll need to create a 
   network client, which will be able to communicate with computer. It's simplest as it can be.
   You'll just send something like "UPDATE_DATABASE" and receive some data as XML. Then
   you'll use some library (probably DOM parser) and show list of songs to the user (it
   may be also sorted into categories).

   When user click to some song, it'll read it's filename (see that attribute in XML above).
   And what's more easy than just send something like: "PLAY_SONG C:\MyMusic...."? Well, 
   maybe one thing - pausing the song. You'll maybe figure out by yourself how to do that.
   :-)

That should be all. I hope I haven't forgotten something important.

Comment: OMG! You are insane man! :)) Very thanks for this answer and it help me and give me such ideas. Now I will try to work on that. :)) Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi again. @Tomáš Zíma I'm having a hard time doing the code part. Could you please help me by citing a working example? :)

Comment: @Kerv I'm very busy currently. If you don't solve it, I'll post some code in the Monday or Tuesday.

Comment: Thanks. It's ok. It's only my experimental project so there's no need to hurry. Thanks! I'll be waiting for that! :))

Comment: Hi @Tomáš Zíma. You not busy? Can you post the working sample code that I've requested? :))

Comment: Hi @Kerv. Why don't we make this as a team project? I'd take care of the computer application (which I'm programming right now) and you'd develop the Android application. I may create project on Google Code and commit the code I've written, so we can discuss how to continue.

Comment: Yes. I'm starting that application. But I don't know how your code run. Maybe i can see the code first before I integrate it in the app.

Comment: At the moment, I'm writing code which will generate XML as shown in the example above. For the beginning, you might create GUI, which will parse that XML and show list of all artists. If user clicks on some artist, it will show all albums and if he finally clicks on album, it will show all songs.

Comment: Yes. Im working on it. Just make it simple. 3 songs is just enough. Just give me a testing ground that will serve as my example. @Tomáš Zíma

Comment: I've just created a [project](https://code.google.com/p/remotemusicplayer/) and commited the [class for managing of the music library](https://code.google.com/p/remotemusicplayer/source/browse/RemoteMusicPlayerServer/src/tools/MusicLibrary.java).

Comment: As a next thing, I'm going to create a music player, network interface and some controller, which will connect all these parts together. After that, I'll just design some nice GUI and work is done.

Comment: Hey man! Really thanks to you. Looking forward for that. You helped me alot!

Comment: Make me a member of your project so i can manage to update the codes that you've posted. @Tomáš Zíma

Comment: Is there a way where I can download all the files that is on the directory? Or can i download them by .rar/.zip? How? @Tomáš Zíma

Comment: I'm not interested in guiding someone through the fully commented simple code in high-level language.

Comment: Now I'm understanding the codes since I've read more about JLayer which you are using on your code. Sorry for that. I need further reading.